# How to assert a primitive.m to a map[string]string

Tags: mongodb, go, casting

I am working with MongoDB in my Go application, and pull some data out and store it in a bson.M (which . Here is an example, of getting the bson.M object from the DB and then printing it (let's call this object `data`):

```
[map[_id:ObjectID("XXXXXXX") address:XX decimal:18 providers:map[currency:value] symbol:LINK]
```

Which looks correct to me.

I think want to loop over the map in the `providers` field (as you can see, it's a map in there as well). I've done a few attempts, but each time I am blocked.

Due to what I've read in the [docs here](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive#M) and the testing I've done, it looks like a bson.M and primitive.M are the same, and they are each treated as a `map[string]interface{}`.

When I attempted to assert it to a `map[string]string` I go a panic error:

```golang
// code run
data["providers"].(map[string]string)

//error received
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is primitive.M, not map[string]string
```

The reason for this, is I want to loop over the `providers` field, and when I try to loop as-is, I get this error:

```
// code to run
for key, provider := range data["providers"] {...}

// error received
cannot range over data["providers"] (map index expression of type interface{})
```

I have read that I might need to do something with marshaling and decoding, but I feel like I'm just missing a step as to why I would need to do those, or how they would help.

In any case to summarize:

1. How does one loop over a primitive.M/bson.M/map[string]interface{}?
2. How does one convert a primitive.M/bson.M/map[string]interface{} to a map[string]string?

It looks like I might be trying to do the opposite of [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975880/convert-mapinterface-interface-to-mapstringstring), and it looks like [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815969/go-cannot-range-over-my-var-type-interface) is giving me conflicting information. Hoping to edit the question as I understand more what my real problem is. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking with Burak Serdar helped give us the answer! You have to assert the `data["providers"]` to a `primitive.M`

```golang
for key, provider := range data["providers"].(primitive.M){...}
```

Key thing to note: primitive.M is handled like a map[string]interface{}

As Burak Serdar mentioned, I cannot assert this instance of a primitive.M to a map[string]string, because the `interface` in `map[string]interface{}` is of type `primitive.M`. So instead, I have to assert the `providers` object to a `primitive.M` object, and then I can loop over it normally.

I cannot convert a primitive.M to a map[string]string

Answer (score 3):

A type assertion for `map[string]interface{}` to `map[string]string` will fail, because it is a type *assertion*, not type *conversion*. It only checks if the interface type is what you think it is, and in this case, it is not. You have to iterate the `map[string]interface{}`, and type-assert the values:

```
for k,v:=range data.(primitive.M)["providers"] {
   if str, ok:=v.(string); ok {
      // Use k and str
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't reach the "if" statement when I tried that, I still get `cannot range over data["providers"] (type interface {})`. Should I be converting data to something else before running the loop?

Comment: Is data primitive.M? If so, try the edited version above

Comment: Ahh that almost worked! So it turns out you have to do `data["providers"].(primitive.M)` (close to what you had) and then you don't have to type-assert the values, although I'm not sure why. I THINK it's because the providers object inside the data object can be asserted to a primitive.M and not a map, since that's what it's an interface of. I'll add an answer to the question to clarify. Thank you for your help!